# Rename files based on symbols in the name

Tags: bash, scripting, renaming

I have a lot of files (images) like this (file names consist only from numbers):

```
123456.jpg
369258.jpg
987123.jpg
...
```

I need to make a copy of each in some other folder (let's name it **output**) and rename each of the file based on numbers in their name, something like this (in pseudocode):

```
outputFileName = String(filename[0]) + String(filename[1]) + String(filename[2]+filename[3]) + ".jpg"
```

So as you can see, the renaming involves getting a certain symbol in file name and sometimes getting a sum of some symbols in file name.

I need to make a script to mass rename all *.jpg in the folder where I put the script based on similar algorithm, and output renamed ones in **output** folder I mentioned earlier.

This script should be workable from macos terminal and windows via cygwin shell.

Comment: Even the *specs* aren't clear!

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: can you please be more specific what remains unclear?

Comment: check this: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename

Comment: What if the sum of 2nd & 3rd character exceeds 10?

Comment: it's ok to be more that 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume main problems are: how to get particular character of bash variable and how to perform addition in bash.

1. To obtain a char from bash variable you can use this form: `${var:START_INDEX:LENGTH}`.
2. To perform addition: `$((ARG1 + ARG2))`

Your resulting script may be like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.jpg
do
  output=${f:0:1}${f:1:1}$((${f:2:1} + ${f:3:1})).jpg
  mv -- "$f" "$output"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [substring extraction](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

The syntax is `${string:position:length}`, where string is the name of the variable, position is the starting position (0 is the first index), and length is the length of the substring.

A script that would create the filenames as specified in the question, and copy them for a folder named "input" to a folder named "output" could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in input/*.jpg
do
    filename="$(basename "$file")"
    firstChar="${filename:0:1}"
    secondChar="${filename:1:1}"
    thirdAndFourthChar="$(( ${filename:2:1} + ${filename:3:1} ))"
    newfilename="$firstChar$secondChar$thirdAndFourthChar.jpg"
    cp "$file" "output/$newfilename"
done
```